# One liner to check two decimal strings differ only by 1 ulp

Tags: java

I have two decimal numbers in String form that are rounded slightly differently. I want a function that would treat them as "equal" if they only  differ by 1 ulp (i.e. only the last digit differs by 1).

Currently the most readable form I can come up with is like:

```
private static boolean diffByUlp(String oldVal, String newVal) {
    BigDecimal nb = new BigDecimal(newVal);
    return nb.subtract(new BigDecimal(oldVal)).abs().equals(nb.ulp());
}
```

However, I'd really like a way to do this in one expression (so it fits in an `if` statement) and avoid using the expensive `BigDecimal`s.

(BTW: they differ by more than 1 double (binary) ulp.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: My initial thought on this is that if you are given `String` instances modelling the decimals, and a `BigDecimal` is the only feasible way of representing such strings, then you'll just have to suck it.

Comment: "However, I'd really like a way to do this in one expression (so it fits in an if statement)" - it's very unlikely that you'll come up with anything as easy to understand as a separate method call.

Comment: In terms of performance, do you need to handle "1.0000" and "1.00" for example? If you know that the strings for equal values will be the same length, you could potentially stick to string operations, although that's slightly icky.

Comment: @JonSkeet Very good point about the String length. I am glad I didn't use String manipulation for this then.... My main concern about `BigDecimal` is the amount of object allocation involved for a frequently-used equals method. For now, I'll put this code in and see if anyone notices.

Comment: Why using `BigDecimal` just to parse the values? `Double.parseDouble` can also convert a `String` into a decimal value and is more efficient. The advantage of `BigDecimal` is that it does not loose precision when inputs get really large. `return Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(oldVal) - Double.parseDouble(newVal)) - 1.0 < 0.00001`. Note that comparing `double` values should not be done with `==`, you should allow some small room for precision loss.

Comment: @Zabuza I guess you meant to divide the two doubles instead of substract? I tried something like this first, but it didn't work. However, I now think I probably implemented it wrong somehow and it's now working. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: @billc.cn Thanks for the suggestion, posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to compactly check if two decimal values only differ by at most `1`. For example `3.2` and `2.4` (difference is `0.8`).

---

First you should note that the only purpose of `BigDecimal` is to provide *infinite* space and precision in contrast to the limited datatype `double` (same holds for `BigInteger` and `int`). However you only use it to parse a decimal value from a `String`. Using that class only for that purpose is quite a big overhead, as you already mentioned. Parsing values can also be done with the `Double#parseDouble` method ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-)), it returns a compact small `double` value.

---

All in all your code could look like this:

```
private static boolean differAtMostByOne(final String oldVal, final String newVal) {
    final double oldValAsDouble = Double.parseDouble(oldVal);
    final double newValAsDouble = Double.parseDouble(newVal),

    final double difference = Math.abs(oldValAsDouble - newValAsDouble);

    final double compareTo = 1.0;
    final double precision = 0.000001;
    final boolean differByAtMostOne = difference <= compareTo + precision;

    return differByAtMostOne;
}
```

Or the same compact:

```
private static boolean differAtMostByOne(final String oldVal, final String newVal) {
    return Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(oldVal) - Double.parseDouble(newVal)) < 1.000001;
}
```

---

Note that a direct comparison with the value `1.0` should be avoided when comparing with decimal values. Instead you should allow a small region around the value to account for precision loss.

Else it could be that you input values whose difference is exactly `1` but the computer may represent it by a value like `1.000000000000000001` and the program should also accept it thus the precision region.

Comment: Even though I think Zabuza misunderstood the "diff by 1" bit (I meant 4.0000000 and 3.9999999 kind of situation), I went with this structure as it's the most efficient for my use case.

Comment: Oh, alright. Feel free to edit the answer and include your correct solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for a performance effective solution since you've already mentioned that using `BigDecimal` is too expensive in your case. Although giving advice on performance without knowing the whole context is quite tricky. You may consider a solution based on comparing characters from both decimal numbers stored as a `String`. It may give you a quick boost if numbers you compare are usually different starting from very first digits (e.g. comparing `120.0001` with `512.0` can be easily tracked just by comparing first character in both strings). But if for most cases your numbers are pretty close then you might stick to `BigDecimal` - it's all about measuring the performance with real data.

Below you can find an exemplary solution based on comparing characters from strings. It handles a case where two decimal numbers uses different precision. Also when comparing `"1.00"` with `"1.00001"` the first number is "treated" as `"1.00000"`. You can use this class as a utility class that provides you a single static method that you can use in any `if` statement.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

final class StringDecimal {

    private static final Map<Integer, Integer> charToInt = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    static {
        charToInt.put(48, 0);
        charToInt.put(49, 1);
        charToInt.put(50, 2);
        charToInt.put(51, 3);
        charToInt.put(52, 4);
        charToInt.put(53, 5);
        charToInt.put(54, 6);
        charToInt.put(55, 7);
        charToInt.put(56, 8);
        charToInt.put(57, 9);
    }

    private static boolean areEqual(String num1, String num2) {
        int size = Math.min(num1.length(), num2.length()) - 1;

        // 1. Compare first n-1 characters where n is max common length for both strings
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (num1.charAt(i) != num2.charAt(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        int lastDigitDiff = Math.max(num1.charAt(size), num2.charAt(size)) - Math.min(num1.charAt(size), num2.charAt(size));

        // 2. Check last common digit
        if (lastDigitDiff > 1) {
            return false;
        }

        // 3. If both decimal numbers have same size, they are equal at this moment
        if (num1.length() == num2.length()) {
            return true;
        }

        if (num1.length() > num2.length()) {
            return testRemainingDigits(num1, size);
        }

        return testRemainingDigits(num2, size);
    }

    private static boolean testRemainingDigits(String num, int size) {
        int lastDigitsSum = 0;
        int lastDigit = charToInt.getOrDefault((int) num.charAt(num.length() - 1), 0);

        // 1. Check if last digit is equal to 1
        if (lastDigit > 1) {
            return false;
        }

        // 2. Sum all remaining digits from longer string and accept sum == 1
        for (int i = num.length() - 1; i > size; i--) {
            lastDigitsSum += charToInt.getOrDefault((int) num.charAt(i), 0);
        }

        return lastDigit == 0 && lastDigitsSum == 0 ||
            lastDigit == 1 && lastDigitsSum == 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Object>> numbers = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList("1.00", "1.000000", true),
            Arrays.asList("120.0", "121.0", false),
            Arrays.asList("120.0", "120.1", true),
            Arrays.asList("1024.00001", "1024.00000", true),
            Arrays.asList("1024.00002", "1024.00000", false),
            Arrays.asList("1024.00001", "1024.0000", true),
            Arrays.asList("1024.00001", "1024", true),
            Arrays.asList("1024.00010", "1024", false),
            Arrays.asList("1024.00002", "1024", false),
            Arrays.asList("1024.00001", "1025.00001", false)
        );

        for (List<Object> data : numbers) {
            String num1 = (String) data.get(0);
            String num2 = (String) data.get(1);
            boolean expected = (boolean) data.get(2);
            boolean result = areEqual(num1, num2);
            String status = expected == result ? "OK" : "FAILED";

            System.out.println("["+status+"] " + num1 + " == " + num2 + " ? " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

It's very imperative, but it's still quite easy to understand what happens under the hood. Complexity of this algorithm is **O(n)**.

Running this exemplary program produces following output:

```
[OK] 1.00 == 1.000000 ? true
[OK] 120.0 == 121.0 ? false
[OK] 120.0 == 120.1 ? true
[OK] 1024.00001 == 1024.00000 ? true
[OK] 1024.00002 == 1024.00000 ? false
[OK] 1024.00001 == 1024.0000 ? true
[OK] 1024.00001 == 1024 ? true
[OK] 1024.00010 == 1024 ? false
[OK] 1024.00002 == 1024 ? false
[OK] 1024.00001 == 1025.00001 ? false
```

I hope it will help you coming up with the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have high expectations in a very "floating" area.
Still one, not so serious, answer:

```
static boolean probablySame(String x, String y) {
    return Math.abs(x.hashCode() - y.hashCode()) <= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need this only for Strings with the same lenght. Following might be a possible solution.

- check that the strings are equal, except the last digit
- check that the last digit is not more of then by one

The snippet should only demonstrate the principal. Further optimization possible.

```
static boolean diffByUlp(String s1, String s2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    char c1 = s1.charAt(s1.length() - 1);
    char c2 = s2.charAt(s2.length() - 1);
    if (c1 >= c2) {
        return c1-c2 <= 1;
    }
    return c2-c1 <= 1;
}
```